# Unix timestamp converting by python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a time(String) to unix timestamp, then convert it back to readable datetime, however, there are 7 hours different. What is the problem in my python code?

```
import datetime

#Convert a Datetime String to unix timestamp   
def get_Timestamp_from_String(datetimeStr):    

    timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimeStr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp())*1000

    return timestamp


# Convert unix timestamp to DateTime    
def get_Datetime_from_Timestamp(timestamp):

    dt = pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='ms')

    return dt
```

Test the datetime: "2016-04-01 01:10:04", however, if I convert it back, then I got the result: '2016-04-01 08:10:04', there are 7 hours different

```
timestamp = get_Timestamp_from_String("2016-04-01 01:10:04")
res = get_Datetime_from_Timestamp(timestamp)
print(res)

>>>Timestamp('2016-04-01 08:10:04')
```

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Timezone issues?

Comment: @IanS I feel very strange, I didn't give any timezone in both functions, so the default timezone should be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `to_datetime` twice, for ms divide by `10**6`:

```
datetimeStr = '2016-04-01 01:10:04'
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(datetimeStr).value //10**6
print (timestamp)
1459473004000

dt = pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='ms')
print (dt)
2016-04-01 01:10:04
```

For `ns`, native format of timestamps in `numpy` dividing is not necessary:

```
datetimeStr = '2016-04-01 01:10:04'
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(datetimeStr).value
print (timestamp)
1459473004000000000

dt = pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='ns')
print (dt)
2016-04-01 01:10:04
```

But if have timezone information:

```
datetimeStr = '2016-04-01 01:10:04-07:00'
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(datetimeStr).value //10**6
print (timestamp)
1459498204000

dt = pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='ms')
print (dt)
2016-04-01 08:10:04
```

Comment: @jezrael , thanks very much for the answer. But, I think, it is so strange, that the result from `pd.to_datetime(...)` is different from `datetime.datetime.strptime(...)`, I can not understand it...

Comment: Hard question for me - but I think pandas `to_datetime` is more general.